# visual studio access violation reading location 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am receiving data in TCP in C++ using Qt library. I store the received packet in a `QByteArray`, but after reading the whole data, I face this error in debug. At the end, I try to clear the buffer, but I face this problem while trying to clear it too.

Here is my code :

```
void AvaNPortTester::scoket_readyRead()
{
    ui.lineEdit_Sending_Status_->setText("Sent");
    ui.lineEdit_Sending_Status_->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(50, 255, 50);  }");
    tcpSocket_data_buffer_.append(tcpSocket_->readAll());

    //qDebug() << serialport_data_buffer_.size();
    //auto ddd = QString::number(tcpSocket_data_buffer_.size());// +" : " + tcpSocket_data_buffer_.toHex();
    //ui.lableSocketRead->setText(ddd);
    bool read_aain = false;
    QByteArray dummy(int(1446), Qt::Initialization::Uninitialized);
    int reminded_data = 0;
    int dummy_size = 0;
    int frame_size = 0;
    int l_size = 0;     

    int total_size_rcvd = tcpSocket_data_buffer_.size();
    //int total_size_rcvd_b = total_size_rcvd_b;
    int temp = 0;
    while (total_size_rcvd != 0)
    {
        if(total_size_rcvd != 0){
        auto packet = tcpSocket_data_buffer_.mid(0, 1446);
        auto rem = tcpSocket_data_buffer_.mid(1446);//****1146

        tcpSocket_data_buffer_ = rem;

        QDataStream streamdata(packet);


        uint8_t  Sync_Header[3];
        auto ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&Sync_Header, 3);

        uint8_t  Total_size[2];
        ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&Total_size, 2);
        int t_size = Total_size[0] * 256 + Total_size[1];


        uint8_t  Reserved[2];
        ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&Reserved, 2);

        frame_size = t_size - 2;
        reminded_data = t_size - 2;
        while (frame_size != 0)
        {

            uint8_t  portid;
            ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&portid, 1);

            //ui.lineEdit_FileSize->setText(QString::number(fileSend_2Ser->size()));

            uint8_t  ProtocolID;
            ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&ProtocolID, 1);

            uint8_t  MoreFragmentFlag;
            ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&MoreFragmentFlag, 1);

            uint8_t  Seq;
            ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&Seq, 1);

            uint8_t  size[2];
            ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&size, 2);
            l_size = size[0] * 256 + size[1];

            if (packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_started[portid] == false) {
                uint8_t  DDCMP_Header[14];
                ss = streamdata.readRawData((char*)&DDCMP_Header, 14);
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] = DDCMP_Header[7] + 256 * DDCMP_Header[8];
                temp = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid];
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_started[portid] = true;
            }
            QByteArray ddcmp_datap(int(l_size), Qt::Initialization::Uninitialized);
            streamdata.readRawData(ddcmp_datap.data(), l_size - 14);
            if ((pre_more_frag == 0) && (MoreFragmentFlag == 0)) {
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_ended[portid] = true;
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] = l_size;
                temp = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid];
            }
            else if ((pre_more_frag == 0) && (MoreFragmentFlag == 1)) {
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_ended[portid] = false;
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] = l_size + 16;
                temp = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid];
            }
            else if ((pre_more_frag == 1) && (MoreFragmentFlag == 1)) {
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_ended[portid] = false;
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] + l_size;
                temp = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid];
            }
            else if ((pre_more_frag == 1) && (MoreFragmentFlag == 0)) {
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_ended[portid] = true;
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid] + l_size;
                temp = packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid];
            }


            if (MoreFragmentFlag == 1) {
                pre_more_frag = 1;
            }
            else {
                pre_more_frag = 0;
            }
            int ff = 0;
            if (packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_ended[portid] == true) {
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_started[portid] = false;
                packet_flags.Ser2Eth.packet_started[portid] = false;
                set_port_id_flag(portid, packet_flags.Ser2Eth.protocol_payload_size[portid], ProtocolID);
                pre_more_frag = 0;
            }

            reminded_data = reminded_data - 6 - l_size;
            //ui.lableSocketRead->setText(ddcmp_datap.toHex());

            frame_size = frame_size - l_size - 6;
        }//end of while (frame_size != 0)

        uint8_t sync_footer[3];
        streamdata.readRawData((char *)&sync_footer, 3);
        dummy_size = 1446 - t_size - 8;
        uint8_t dummy_data[1000];
        streamdata.readRawData((char *)&dummy_data, dummy_size);
        total_size_rcvd = total_size_rcvd - 1446;
        if (total_size_rcvd == 0) {
            tcpSocket_data_buffer_.clear();
        }

    } //end of if
    }//end of while()
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is with the tcpSocket_data_buffer_.

Comment: In those topics, it is said that the problem is that it tries to access to a memory location which doesn't exist. for example, when there is an array of length 20(arr[]), and we try to access to Arr[21], this error will be arisen. in my code, this error is happened while reading tcpSocket_data_buffer_ which is of QByteArray type.  when I receive a packet, i get its size at the beginning, and I read the whole data, It works fine till the end of the function. and I expect that it exit the "while (total_size_rcvd != 0)" , and exit the function. but it seems that it deosnt exit the function and

Comment: and while exiting the "while" , this error arises in debug. I though that maybe I should clear the buffer, so I used tcpSocket_data_buffer_.clear(); to clear the buffer. but when the code reaches to this line, the same error happens.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the details there. Afterwards you can delete the comments.